# Conditional IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, importrange

In Google Sheets, I'm using `IMPORTRANGE` to pull in data from to a large sheet.

One field is a dollar amount. I would like to import the dollar amount and replace any zero amount with a specific dollar amount. For example, if the number is `$100`, I want to import `$100`. But if the number is `$0`, I want to import it but replace the `$0` with `$50`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can use simple **`IF`** formula for that, like:

  ```
  =IF(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet1!A1")="$0", "$50", IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet1!A1"))
  ```

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet1!A1:A")="$0", "$50", 
                   IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet1!A1:A")))
  ```
- to avoid **`#N/A`** wrap it into **`IFERROR`**

Comment: Sorry to ask such an ignorant question ... what does "ID" represent? The field name?

Comment: ID is a number from url. in importrange you have two options: to either use URL like for example: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16nnuzNRx_kGGJm1EBVX7kBT2bfW1-2TYwSiuaLF-QIA/edit#gid=187215959` or ID: `16nnuzNRx_kGGJm1EBVX7kBT2bfW1-2TYwSiuaLF-QIA` from it (shorter option). it's the unique number from between `d/` and `/edit`